# PhantomJS failing on remote ajax field check

Tags: ajax, phantomjs

I developed a script to complete & submit a remote form via PhantomJS (version 2.1). For testing I built a local approximation of the remote form which included an ajax field check upon input (so, you enter an email address in the `email` field, and after a second it checks to see if it's a valid input). My phantom script fills out the fields, waits a few seconds for an error to be thrown, and then carries on to submit the form if everything looks okay. This all worked just fine with everything running on `localhost`.

However, as soon as I switch to making the call to the remote webpage (which is a third-party site; I have no access to make changes to it), it fails when the remote page performs the ajax check on fields. I have the following [onResourceError](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html) function:

```
page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
    system.stderr.writeLine('= onResourceError()');
    system.stderr.writeLine('  - unable to load url: "' + resourceError.url + '"');
    system.stderr.writeLine('  - error code: ' + resourceError.errorCode + ', description: ' + resourceError.errorString );
};
```

...and if I run the following line (in a Windows command prompt):

`phantomjs.exe form-process.js "https://contact.site.com/auth/form?params=that&are=always&the=same" "clarence@email.com"`

I get the following error:

```
https://contact.site.com/ajax/email-check?email=clarence@email.com"
    - error code: 302,
    - description: Error downloading "https://contact.site.com/ajax/email-check?email=clarence@email.com"
    - server replied: Bad request
```

I am running this from a local environment but with no SSL certificate installed, so I assumed (based on the description of the [302 error code](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qnetworkreply.html#NetworkError-enum): `the requested operation is invalid for this protocol`) that it was a cross-protocol issue. But running the phantomJS line with any combination of `--ssl-protocol=any`, `--ignore-ssl-errors=yes` or `--web-security=false` yields the same results.

I may be misunderstanding these modes for phantomJS, but I assumed that `--ssl-protocol=any` would dismiss this issue, but would I still need to have a local SSL cert to get this to work? Or is there another issue here?

Comment: You could try both upgrading and downgrading your PhantomJS version. Which version do you use, btw?

Comment: It may also depend on how you're opening the page. Have you tried `--local-to-remote-url-access=true`? Just to be sure, you're specifying the additional commandline options at the second position, ex.: `phantomjs --web-security=false script.js`?

Comment: @ArtjomB. Sorry - totally meant to put that in my post and forgot. Currently using v2.1.1. Post updated!

Comment: @ArtjomB. I hadn't seen the `--local-to-remote-url-access` parameter before, so thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to make a difference - I still get the same errors. And yes, any CLI options are set at the second position, before the script name.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Ah ha! Development: I downgraded to PhantomJS 1.9.7, and I'm no longer getting the error as above. The form submission is apparently failing and it's not clear why - but no more `Bad request` errors.